# Problems with creating Linear Guide using Configurable joint

Tags: unity, movement, joints

I'm trying to create an Linear Guide mechanism using *Configurable Joint* (I think this joint is better than other for this situation). I connected an orange cube to another object (let's call it frame) and set 0.05 mass to the orange cube:
[image]
Then I locked all Motions and Angular Motions:
[image]
I thought that I can change orange cube position by changing *Connected Anchor* setting in *Configurable Joint*, but it worked only in simulation. So when I try to change *Connected Anchor* from my script - *Connected Anchor* values just change, but nothing happens on the scene.
There are also some problems with Joints - Why this Joint is not *so* rigid (when I move *frame* - oragne cube starts shaking like jelly) and how can I make it more rigid with this difference of masses (orange cube mass is 0.05, *frame* mass is 1)?
And is there any way to create Linear Guide mechanism in Unity, so an object can be firmly connected to another one and move relatively to the second one only by one axis?
Here is the scripts I used to change *Connected Anchor* values and move *frame*:

```cs
public class TestLiftScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject lift;

    float v = 0;
    float h = 0;
    float r = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        DevMove();
        transform.localPosition += new Vector3 (h * Time.deltaTime, 0, v * Time.deltaTime);

        lift.transform.localPosition += new Vector3(0, r * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }

    private void DevMove()
    {
        if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            float sp = 0.1f;
            v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * -sp;
            h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * -sp;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
            {
                r = -sp;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
                {
                    r = sp;
                }
                else r = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** I read the post that @DMGregory posted here, but there is a problem. When I move *frame* object and orange cube simultaneously, the *frame* starts just sliding away (when I stop pressing keys). Like this:
[image]
And I also edited my code.

Comment: You may be interested in [How do I configure a joint for a sliding door in Unity?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/129659/39518)

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, it's really interesting. I should have a look